# Convert .net C# web application into desktop app

Tags: asp.net

i want to convert my web base application in to desktop base application...Kindly Give solution..

Comment: I don't think there is any direct way of doing this.

Comment: I'm amazed this got upvoted...

Answer (score 2):

Conversion of Asp.net web application to a desktop application is almost not possible. WebForms and WinForms are different and should be designed differently.
Maintain a common business logic in a class library and reuse it. But the UI should be designed from scratch because webforms are not winforms and (.aspx file cannot be converted to WinForm)

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is any direct way nut you can do it in manually by creating new desktop app project and implementing your logic in it.

Else you will have to bind web kit with your project. Webkit is HTML rendering engine that comes with Safari and Chrome. it is open source so any one can use it.. It includes browser with your application so it will work without installing any browser... But probably need net connection according to your applications requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Compile your `asp.net` page with [WestWindAspnetCompiler](http://www.west-wind.com/tools/aspnetcompiler.asp) , deploy on your IIS and use your web application with `loalhost` .

Comment: OP want to change web application to window application?

Comment: Can not convert web app to window app > i think that's the best way :)